# REST API - Add same item with different custom options to cart in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api

I'm adding products to cart via REST API. I NEED to add the same product but with different options, However, when I post the 2nd request, The 2nd product is not added as new order item, but only the quantity is increased. looks like Magento is not considering the different options product as a separate item, rather, it just compares the SKU and adds the quantity regardless of the options.

is there a way to make Magento add multiple instances of the same SKU item (with different options) as separate items?

below is how the items of the order differ

```
   {
        "name": "product 1",
        "sku": "ABC",
        "qty": 1,
        "product_option": {
          "extension_attributes": {
            "custom_options": [
              {
                "option_id": "color",
                "option_value": "blue"
              }
            ]
          }
        }

    }

   {
        "name": "product 2",
        "sku": "ABC",
        "qty": 3,
        "product_option": {
          "extension_attributes": {
            "custom_options": [
              {
                "option_id": "color",
                "option_value": "red"
              }
            ]
          }
        }

    }
```

Comment: How about if you use child SKU instead?

Comment: the options are not predefined , the options input are TEXT fields where user can type any thing

Comment: Seems it's a problem on frontend too.

Comment: i managed to use custom options on the front end , however , magetno saves only the 1st item options

Comment: So this is obviously a Magento bug. You can report it via github.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am running into the same scenario on my Magento 2.2.7 setup.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/158008)